# SQL Server query select multiple columns where

Tags: sql-server, select, where-clause

Using SQL Server I want to return the top 1 `ScanDateTime` and the corresponding ID, in a single query, where the ID=124.

So far I have

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    ScanDateTime and ID 
FROM TBL_ScanQueue 
WHERE IPAddress = 124
```

But this is wrong. I am sure this is a very simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need a comma between your selected columns, not an "and".  I think you'll also want to add an order by statement to get the most recent ScanDateTime.

```
SELECT TOP 1 
ScanDateTime,
ID
FROM
TBL_ScanQueue WHERE IPAddress=124
ORDER BY ScanDateTime DESC
```